# How to set cell width size for BeautifulTable?

Tags: python, terminal, python-beautifultable

I'm using the python module [`BeautifulTable`](https://beautifultable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to emit a table to a console. It's wrapping some of the headers and contents and I'd like to set the cell width so it doesn't do that.

I've tried setting the widths via `table.column_widths` (as per the docs) but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](http://beautifultable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/beautifultable.html):

> column_widths
>
> get/set width for the columns of the table.
>
> Width of the column specifies the max number of characters a column can contain. Larger characters are handled according to the value of width_exceed_policy.

Thus column_widths only handles the max number of characters in a column. For handling overflowing text `width_exceed_policy` has to be used.

```
table.width_exceed_policy = BeautifulTable.WEP_ELLIPSIS
```

From the docs it can be one of the following:

1. `BeautifulTable.WEP_WRAP` : An item is wrapped so every line fits within it’s column width.
2. `BeautifulTable.WEP_STRIP` : An item is stripped to fit in it’s column.
3. `BeautifulTable.WEP_ELLIPSIS` : An item is stripped to fit in it’s column and appended with …(Ellipsis).

Answer (score 3):

You can specify width using [`table.columns.width`](https://beautifultable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/beautifultable.html#beautifultable.BTColumnCollection.width), e.g.

```
table.columns.width = 30
```

or

```
table.columns.width = [20, 30, 40]
```

If the table contains dynamic data, it may be better to increase [`maxwidth`](https://beautifultable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/beautifultable.html#beautifultable.BeautifulTable.maxwidth) from the default `80`:

```
table = BeautifulTable(maxwidth=120)
```

You could also wrap the data yourself with the desired width before putting it to a column. The [`textwrap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html) stdlib module may be useful for that. For JSON data it may help to pretty-print it with [`json.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps), e.g.:

```
json.dumps(data, indent=2)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **BeautifulTable 1.0.0** you have the following syntax:

```
table.columns.width = [12,5,8,10,6,33]
print(table)
```

while the older syntax `table.column_widths = [12,5,8,10,6,33]` tends to be automatically overriden when `print(table)` is called.

From the official [release notes](https://beautifultable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html):

> Updated behaviour of BeautifulTable.columns.width (earlier BeautifulTable.column_widths). It no longer overrides user specified widths by default. You can reset it to default by setting it to "auto"

Answer (score 1):

Per the [docs](http://beautifultable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/beautifultable.html) and the [change log](https://pypi.org/project/beautifultable/) for v0.8.0, controlling column width can be handled by setting the `column_widths` attribute:

```
>>> table.column_widths = 5
>>> print(table.column_widths)
PositiveIntegerMetaData<5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5>

>>> table.column_widths = [10, 20, 5, 7, 10, 10, 5]
>>> print(table.column_widths)
PositiveIntegerMetaData<10, 20, 5, 7, 10, 10, 5>
```

Note that the most recent change log also says it dropped support for Python v3.3
I have only tested this in Python v3.7.5 where, as soon as the table is printed again, these values are overwritten.

If you're using v3.3+ and you don't want to truncate or wrap your headers/fields then the only 'work around' that I have found is to set the `max_table_width` to a value large enough to accommodate all your row contents + padding + borders:

```
>>> table.max_table_width = 150
```

Of course, this has its obvious limits.